# WebAPI core is returning Internal Server Error with async controllers

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple Repository and every time that I try to call it doesn't work, it works if I remove the `async`, I never had this problem before. Here's what I did.

The Register Controller has a `HttpPost` That means I'm trying to POST and it Only works if I remove the `async` from the method.

The Register Model :

```
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string User { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
```

I'm using POSTMAN to test the API :

1. Headers - `Content-type/application/json`
2. Body :

   `{
      "Email":"someemail@outlook.com",
      "User":"Someuser",
      "Password":"00000000"
   }`

URL : `http://localhost:57326/api/Register/Register`

The Logic :

```
public interface IRegister
{
    Task<int> Register(RegisterModel register); 
}

[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class RegisterController : ControllerBase
{
    public IRegister register { get; set; }
    public RegisterController(IRegister Register)
    {
        this.register = Register;
    }

    [HttpPost("Register")]
    //[Authorize(Roles = "Host")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
    {
        var result = await register.Register(model);
        if(result > 0)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

As the image shows, It returns a 500 Internal Error WITH the `async` Task on the action method, removing those, The Call (POST) proceeds.

Comment: `it is not working` is a rather broad statement. It does not tell us what is actually happening as apposed what was expected. Can you reformat the question so we get a clearer picture of the current problem and what you are **actually** trying to do? See the [ask] page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: If I remove the async I get the response. `HttpPost` Meaning, that I'm trying to POST a Json data.

Comment: I changed the question.

Comment: 500 is a generic HTTP error when something goes wrong server-side.  Have you stepped through you controller action code to see which line is taking the error and what the underlying exception really is?

Comment: Share us the implementation for `IRegister`. Try to debug your project and check the ourput windows in VS.

Comment: Seeing the exception being thrown would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you meant by removing `async`, because there is an `await` in your method.

I suspect what is happening when you remove_`async`_and_other_things the controller returns before `.Register` does the work.

I suggest adding `try { } catch (Exception ex ) { }` inside the controller method (with the `async` 'version') and executing the POST and inspecting the exception.